# Please talk me through MySQL collations

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, collation

I'm setting up a new MySQL database for a website and I want the content-type to be UTF-8.

Why does MySQL have so many different, seemingly language-specific collations for UTF-8? Isn't the point of UTF-8 that it will encompass all those languages without switching encodings? What are those "_bin" and "_cs" and "_ci" notations? Will choosing "_bin" make some operations case-sensitive?

My site will be mostly in English, but obviously I would like to be able to do things like, paste a Japanese character into my text without incident.

Comment: ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) (FAQ). "This question does not show any research effort" (Downvote button alt text). If your question about specific software can be answered from a quick glance at that software's manual...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html) have the best bird's eye view I've read.

Short story . . .

Collations define the order for sorting and comparison. Collations ending in "_cs" are case-sensitive; "_ci" means case-insensitive. For text, char, or varchar, you *probably* want one of those two.

The order for sorting and comparison with a "_bin" collation is determined by the binary values of the characters. Values from a "_bin" collation are copied byte-for-byte to the target column. (Values from the other collations might be converted to a different character set.) All characters are significant, including trailing spaces. *Uppercase* and *lowercase* are meaningless.